# how to find the first upper character in a text using postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres sql that has two columns that both contain the same  name data, the parts of which are distinguished by letter case. For example:

```
col1         col2
johnSmith    johnSmith
```

I want col1 to be just `"john"` and col2 to be just `"Smith"`.

The division between the name parts is at the first uppercase letter.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update mytable set
col1 = regexp_replace(col1, '[A-Z].*', 'm'),
col2 = regexp_replace(col2, '^[a-z]*', '')
```

Both calls to [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) target the part to be *removed* and do that by replacing with nothing (a blank).

The first regex `[A-Z].*` matches the first uppercase letter and everything thereafter.

The second regex `^[a-z]*` matches the start of the string add all lowercase letters that immediately follow.

Answer (score 1):

Use two functions, substring use a REGEX expresion to find first uppercase character, and position returns it position inside the string.

```
select position((select substring('my Firts Uppercase', '([A-Z])')) in 'my Firts Uppercase');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this :

```
select t[1] as col1,t[2] as col2 from (
  select regexp_matches(login,'([a-z]*)([A-Z].*)') t from (
        select 'johnSmith'::character varying as login
 ) a 
 ) b
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `substring`and regex. Query:

```
SELECT substring(a from '^[a-z]*'),  --select lower case letters from the start
       substring(b from '[A-Z].*')   --select Capital starting string from the end...
FROM t1                              --... ending with '.*$' would probably pay off
```

returns:

```
john | Smith
```

Then UPDATE it back:

```
UPDATE t1
SET a=substring(a from '^[a-z]*'),
    b=substring(b from '[A-Z].*')
FROM t1
```